# Is $f \in W^{1,1}[a,b]$ equivalent to $f$ absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

$f$ is a function defined on $[a,b]$. Then $f \in W^{1,1}$ is equivalent to $f$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: Yes, this is true. A proof can be found in: "One dimensional variational problems" by G. Buttazzo et al. starting from page 84.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\in W^{1,1}\big([0,1]\big)$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous, as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_k)-f(y_k)|=\sum_{k=1}^n \Big|\int_{x_k}^{y_k}f'(x)\,dx\Big|
\le\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{x_k}^{y_k}|f'(x)|\,dx,
$$
and then use the fact that: *If $g\in L^1$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that $m(E)<\delta$ implies $\int_{E}|g|<\varepsilon$.*

On the other hand, if $f$ is absolutely continuous, then there exists a $g\in L^1$, such that
$$
f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x g(t)\,dt,
$$
in which case, one can show that $f$ possesses a weak derivative in $L^1$, which coincides with $g$ a.e., and hence $f\in W^{1,1}$.